# $m_i, n_j$ integers and $\{m_i\}_{i=1}^{k}\neq\{n_j\}_{j=1}^{k'}.$ Does $\sum\frac{1}{m_i}=\sum\frac{1}{n_j}\implies\sum m_i\neq\sum n_j?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, examples-counterexamples, natural-numbers, egyptian-fractions

Suppose $\{m_i\}_{i=1}^{k}$ and $\{n_j\}_{j=1}^{k'}$ are each finite subsets of $\mathbb{N},$ $\{m_i\}_{i=1}^{k}\neq\{n_j\}_{j=1}^{k'},$  and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{i=k}\frac{1}{m_i} = \sum_{j=1}^{j=k'} \frac{1}{n_j}. $ Is it true then that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{i=k}m_i \neq \sum_{j=1}^{j=k'} n_j\ ? $

The contrapositive statement seems similar in difficulty.

Comment: Is $k\neq k'$ else you could just take both sequences to be the same right?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a condition. Edited now.

Comment: Any sum $\sum_{i=1}^h\frac{1}{m_i}<1$ can be extended to a sum $\sum_{i=1}^k\tfrac{1}{m_i}=1$, and you can fold in any other sum $\sum_{j=1}^l\tfrac{1}{n_j}=1$ by replacing $\tfrac{1}{m_i}$ by $\sum_{j=1}^l\tfrac{1}{m_in_j}$. This should give you plenty of room to play around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why, of course not.

$$
\frac13+\frac1{12}+\frac1{21}+\frac1{28}=\frac14+\frac16+\frac1{18}+\frac1{36}=\frac12$$
while
$$
3+12+21+28=4+6+18+36=64
$$

Comment: How did you come up with this?

Comment: Checked the list of all 5-tuples with sum of reciprocals equal to 1 (which I just happened to have handy), sorted it by the sum...